# How do I use pandas to get averages in a column contingent on the data of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas through jupyterlab to do a somewhat-complicated analysis on an Excel spreadsheet. I want to calculate the average time differential in a column ("delta") when the corresponding cell in another column ("orders") has a gap.

In other words:

```
Orders     Delta
1          00:00:00
2          00:05:32
4          00:10:32
5          00:12:83
6          00:15:83
```

I would like to be able to get the average time delta between orders 2 and 4 (as #3 is missing), across an entire spreadsheet. I would then want to get the average between orders where there is no gap (Orders are sequential).

I apologize for being so vague, I am somewhat (very) new to Python and I'm having trouble even getting my head around how one would accomplish this. I currently have functioning code that pulls from an XLSX and calculates the "delta" from an order date time, but have hit a wall with the above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this:

1. You want the places where there is no "gap" in `Orders`, i.e. there the difference in the orders index is exactly 1. You can get these locations by `df['Orders'].diff()==1`
2. You want the time difference at these locations.`df['Delta'].diff()[df['Orders'].diff()==1]`
3. You want their average: `df['Delta'].diff()[df['Orders'].diff()==1].mean()`

I got `Timedelta('0 days 00:03:47.666666')` as an output from this code.

 Is this what you needed?

Comment: This was exactly it, thank you so much. As I said above, I couldn't wrap my head around how I would even approach it.